# What makes a computer artificially intelligent?

Tags: consciousness, artificial-intelligence

What features would make a computer be considered truly artificially intelligent? Better question yet, what would make a computer truly intelligent and conscious? (true artificial intelligence is an oxymoron - true fake intelligence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What features would make a computer be considered truly artificially intelligent?

When the intelligence is made and designed by human (or other "sentients"), instead of something that occurs naturally. "Artificial" does not carry the connotation of being fake, it merely means "made by humans".

> Better question yet, what would make a computer truly intelligent and conscientious? (true artificial intelligence is an oxymoron - true fake intelligence)

Define "conscientious", then we might have an answer. There is no oxymoron on the phrase "true artificial intelligence"; it's probably actually a tautology, all "artificial intelligence" are "true artificial intelligence". A "fake artificial intelligence" would be an artificial intelligence that are actually made by nature, and that is an oxymoron.

Comment: That can be defined as my spelling error. (conscious)

Comment: Both consciousness and conscientiousness have the same problem in that they are poorly defined. If you provide a definition, then we might be able to concoct a test that can be used to determine whether a being are conscious/conscientious or not.

Comment: Consciousness is a philosophical term that cannot be easily defined.

Comment: From your answer and comments I see that you, like other people, see that the definition for AI  and qualities of AI are merely philosophical. That is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Yea you must define consciousness first. Then the puzzle will be easier. personally I think that all definitions of consciousness fail because they can't be testable yet,meaning to make some entity have the same properties as humans do.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson - I do not understand your question, because the issue has nothing to do with computers - mixing computers into the mix seems like obfuscation: Your question is really about how to define  intelligence and consciousness. Once they are defined, any object which displays those characteristics, be it biological, mechanical, electrical, nuclear,  chemical... whatever  - is "truly" "intelligent" or "conscious".

Comment: Artificial intelligence means made by humans in the form of  a system of interacting programs all 'in an' operating system 'package' and designed ( by its programmers before it was initialized) to handle any info. processing and management situation. So 'it' doesn't do any on the spot 'thinking', all that is done by previously set up algorithms. Artificial intelligence is an oxymoron..

Comment: @201044: you haven't shown that it's not an oxymoron. All you've done is moving the issue around; now you would need to define what constitutes "thinking", such that an artificial intelligence can't possibly do it but a human intelligence can.

Comment: I was trying to show it is an oxymoron.

Comment: @201044: yes, sorry, I meant you haven't shown that it's an oxymoron. The words "artificial" and "intelligence" do not contradict each other.

Answer (score 3):

First, we'd have to have some idea of what intelligence is.  We know some things that go along with it, but that's not sufficient.  Early on, it seemed plausible that a computer would be intelligent if it could play a good game of chess, but we now have computers that play very strongly but aren't intelligent in any real sense.

Turing tried going with the idea that we'd know it when we saw it with the Turing test, in which a computer would try to convince a human that the computer was a human.  Empirical tests show that people are awfully easy to fool, even with computer systems that really don't see intelligent.  However, I really don't know of any other good test.

Comment: Artificial intelligence doesn't create any novel responses on the spot , it generates combinations of 'prefabricated' info. and processes from prefabricated algorithms put 'in it' by its programmers in the 'past'. So in this sense it is not 'intelligent' making 'new' responses or new programs ad hoc.